# Apportable Xcode 5 empty project compile error

Tags: apportable

i have an created an empty project in xcode 5.  It gave me this error when I did apportable build

'androidshark apple$ apportable load
Building with TARGET_ARCH_ABI:armeabi ARM_NEON:False
Building to /Users/apple/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug
Updating configuration parameters... Building Xcode project /android/shark2/androidshark/androidshark
Scanning build configuration for target androidshark
2013-09-27 13:18:38.657 xcodebuild[83681:313]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-3564/Xcode3Sources/XcodeIDE/Frameworks/DevToolsBase/pbxcore/SpecificationTypes/XCGccMakefileDependencies.m:78
Details:  Failed to load dependencies output contents from `/var/folders/nc/m2ds8dw113l80bkf79bcfqg40000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/5.0-5A1412/Xcode/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/androidshark-Prefix-fiixcbwreansxzhkosqdeekvvhit/androidshark-Prefix.pch.d''. Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “androidshark-Prefix.pch.d” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo=0x7fbabd831650 {NSFilePath=/var/folders/nc/m2ds8dw113l80bkf79bcfqg40000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/5.0-5A1412/Xcode/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/androidshark-Prefix-fiixcbwreansxzhkosqdeekvvhit/androidshark-Prefix.pch.d, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fbabd87f080 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}. User info: {
    NSFilePath = "/var/folders/nc/m2ds8dw113l80bkf79bcfqg40000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/5.0-5A1412/Xcode/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/androidshark-Prefix-fiixcbwreansxzhkosqdeekvvhit/androidshark-Prefix.pch.d";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. No such file or directory\"";
}.
Function: void XCGccMakefileDependenciesParsePathsFromRuleFile(NSString *__strong, F) [F = <lambda at /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-3564/Xcode3Sources/XcodeIDE/Frameworks/DevToolsBase/pbxcore/SpecificationTypes/XCGccMakefileDependencies.m:168:73>]
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fbabd8c0a30>{name = (null), num = 6}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
2013-09-27 13:18:38.699 xcodebuild[83681:4403]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-3564/Xcode3Sources/XcodeIDE/Frameworks/DevToolsBase/pbxcore/SpecificationTypes/XCGccMakefileDependencies.m:78
Details:  Failed to load dependencies output contents from`/var/folders/nc/m2ds8dw113l80bkf79bcfqg40000gn/T/tmpa1EIp5/TARGET_TEMP_DIR/Objects-normal/armv7/sharkAppDelegate.d''. Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “sharkAppDelegate.d” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo=0x7fbabd9be8a0 {NSFilePath=/var/folders/nc/m2ds8dw113l80bkf79bcfqg40000gn/T/tmpa1EIp5/TARGET_TEMP_DIR/Objects-normal/armv7/sharkAppDelegate.d, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fbabd9bd520 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}. User info: {
    NSFilePath = "/var/folders/nc/m2ds8dw113l80bkf79bcfqg40000gn/T/tmpa1EIp5/TARGET_TEMP_DIR/Objects-normal/armv7/sharkAppDelegate.d";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. No such file or directory\"";
}.
Function: void XCGccMakefileDependenciesParsePathsFromRuleFile(NSString ***strong, F) [F = ]
Thread:   {name = (null), num = 7}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
2013-09-27 13:18:38.745 xcodebuild[83681:232b]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-3564/Xcode3Sources/XcodeIDE/Frameworks/DevToolsBase/pbxcore/SpecificationTypes/XCGccMakefileDependencies.m:78
Details:  Failed to load dependencies output contents from `/var/folders/nc/m2ds8dw113l80bkf79bcfqg40000gn/T/tmpa1EIp5/TARGET_TEMP_DIR/Objects-normal/armv7/main.d''. Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “main.d” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo=0x7fbabda275e0 {NSFilePath=/var/folders/nc/m2ds8dw113l80bkf79bcfqg40000gn/T/tmpa1EIp5/TARGET_TEMP_DIR/Objects-normal/armv7/main.d, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fbabda24bf0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}. User info: {
    NSFilePath = "/var/folders/nc/m2ds8dw113l80bkf79bcfqg40000gn/T/tmpa1EIp5/TARGET_TEMP_DIR/Objects-normal/armv7/main.d";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. No such file or directory\"";
}.
Function: void XCGccMakefileDependenciesParsePathsFromRuleFile(NSString *__strong, F) [F = <lambda at /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-3564/Xcode3Sources/XcodeIDE/Frameworks/DevToolsBase/pbxcore/SpecificationTypes/XCGccMakefileDependencies.m:168:73>]
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fbabda25cc0>{name = (null), num = 8}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
Scanning build configuration for target androidsharkTests
2013-09-27 13:18:42.845 xcodebuild[83701:2813]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-3564/Xcode3Sources/XcodeIDE/Frameworks/DevToolsBase/pbxcore/SpecificationTypes/XCGccMakefileDependencies.m:78
Details:  Failed to load dependencies output contents from`/var/folders/nc/m2ds8dw113l80bkf79bcfqg40000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/5.0-5A1412/Xcode/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/androidshark-Prefix-fofkyioslmjpdibzwybriufsgphs/androidshark-Prefix.pch.d''. Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “androidshark-Prefix.pch.d” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo=0x7fd1941b5760 {NSFilePath=/var/folders/nc/m2ds8dw113l80bkf79bcfqg40000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/5.0-5A1412/Xcode/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/androidshark-Prefix-fofkyioslmjpdibzwybriufsgphs/androidshark-Prefix.pch.d, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fd1941b60f0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}. User info: {
    NSFilePath = "/var/folders/nc/m2ds8dw113l80bkf79bcfqg40000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/5.0-5A1412/Xcode/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/androidshark-Prefix-fofkyioslmjpdibzwybriufsgphs/androidshark-Prefix.pch.d";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. No such file or directory\"";
}.
Function: void XCGccMakefileDependenciesParsePathsFromRuleFile(NSString *__strong, F) [F = ]
Thread:   {name = (null), num = 6}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
2013-09-27 13:18:42.887 xcodebuild[83701:2813]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-3564/Xcode3Sources/XcodeIDE/Frameworks/DevToolsBase/pbxcore/SpecificationTypes/XCGccMakefileDependencies.m:78
Details:  Failed to load dependencies output contents from `/var/folders/nc/m2ds8dw113l80bkf79bcfqg40000gn/T/tmpLcA0vT/TARGET_TEMP_DIR/Objects-normal/armv7/sharkAppDelegate.d''. Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “sharkAppDelegate.d” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo=0x7fd1941bec80 {NSFilePath=/var/folders/nc/m2ds8dw113l80bkf79bcfqg40000gn/T/tmpLcA0vT/TARGET_TEMP_DIR/Objects-normal/armv7/sharkAppDelegate.d, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fd1941b4a00 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}. User info: {
    NSFilePath = "/var/folders/nc/m2ds8dw113l80bkf79bcfqg40000gn/T/tmpLcA0vT/TARGET_TEMP_DIR/Objects-normal/armv7/sharkAppDelegate.d";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. No such file or directory\"";
}.
Function: void XCGccMakefileDependenciesParsePathsFromRuleFile(NSString *__strong, F) [F = <lambda at /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-3564/Xcode3Sources/XcodeIDE/Frameworks/DevToolsBase/pbxcore/SpecificationTypes/XCGccMakefileDependencies.m:168:73>]
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fd1941ebf10>{name = (null), num = 6}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
2013-09-27 13:18:42.922 xcodebuild[83701:1703]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-3564/Xcode3Sources/XcodeIDE/Frameworks/DevToolsBase/pbxcore/SpecificationTypes/XCGccMakefileDependencies.m:78
Details:  Failed to load dependencies output contents from`/var/folders/nc/m2ds8dw113l80bkf79bcfqg40000gn/T/tmpLcA0vT/TARGET_TEMP_DIR/Objects-normal/armv7/main.d''. Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “main.d” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo=0x7fd1941f5a30 {NSFilePath=/var/folders/nc/m2ds8dw113l80bkf79bcfqg40000gn/T/tmpLcA0vT/TARGET_TEMP_DIR/Objects-normal/armv7/main.d, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fd1941f59a0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}. User info: {
    NSFilePath = "/var/folders/nc/m2ds8dw113l80bkf79bcfqg40000gn/T/tmpLcA0vT/TARGET_TEMP_DIR/Objects-normal/armv7/main.d";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. No such file or directory\"";
}.
Function: void XCGccMakefileDependenciesParsePathsFromRuleFile(NSString *__strong, F) [F = ]
Thread:   {name = (null), num = 7}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
2013-09-27 13:18:43.116 xcodebuild[83701:1703]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-3564/Xcode3Sources/XcodeIDE/Frameworks/DevToolsBase/pbxcore/SpecificationTypes/XCGccMakefileDependencies.m:78
Details:  Failed to load dependencies output contents from `/var/folders/nc/m2ds8dw113l80bkf79bcfqg40000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/5.0-5A1412/Xcode/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/androidshark-Prefix-gbnbvpzwmdufkrfybjovaydtncti/androidshark-Prefix.pch.d''. Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “androidshark-Prefix.pch.d” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo=0x7fd1941b6650 {NSFilePath=/var/folders/nc/m2ds8dw113l80bkf79bcfqg40000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/5.0-5A1412/Xcode/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/androidshark-Prefix-gbnbvpzwmdufkrfybjovaydtncti/androidshark-Prefix.pch.d, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fd1936c0d40 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}. User info: {
    NSFilePath = "/var/folders/nc/m2ds8dw113l80bkf79bcfqg40000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/5.0-5A1412/Xcode/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/androidshark-Prefix-gbnbvpzwmdufkrfybjovaydtncti/androidshark-Prefix.pch.d";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. No such file or directory\"";
}.
Function: void XCGccMakefileDependenciesParsePathsFromRuleFile(NSString *__strong, F) [F = <lambda at /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-3564/Xcode3Sources/XcodeIDE/Frameworks/DevToolsBase/pbxcore/SpecificationTypes/XCGccMakefileDependencies.m:168:73>]
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fd1941b4a00>{name = (null), num = 7}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
2013-09-27 13:18:43.158 xcodebuild[83701:1703]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-3564/Xcode3Sources/XcodeIDE/Frameworks/DevToolsBase/pbxcore/SpecificationTypes/XCGccMakefileDependencies.m:78
Details:  Failed to load dependencies output contents from`/var/folders/nc/m2ds8dw113l80bkf79bcfqg40000gn/T/tmpLcA0vT/TARGET_TEMP_DIR/Objects-normal/armv7/androidsharkTests.d''. Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “androidsharkTests.d” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo=0x7fd1941b5050 {NSFilePath=/var/folders/nc/m2ds8dw113l80bkf79bcfqg40000gn/T/tmpLcA0vT/TARGET_TEMP_DIR/Objects-normal/armv7/androidsharkTests.d, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fd1941bc7c0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}. User info: {
    NSFilePath = "/var/folders/nc/m2ds8dw113l80bkf79bcfqg40000gn/T/tmpLcA0vT/TARGET_TEMP_DIR/Objects-normal/armv7/androidsharkTests.d";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. No such file or directory\"";
}.
Function: void XCGccMakefileDependenciesParsePathsFromRuleFile(NSString *__strong, F) [F = ]
Thread:   {name = (null), num = 7}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
2013-09-27 13:18:43,231 - build - ERROR - Could not generate build parameters
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/apple/.apportable/SDK/site_scons/build/__init**.py", line 481, in App
    generated, generated_path, main_module = xcode.GenerateBuildParams(env)
  File "/Users/apple/.apportable/SDK/site_scons/build/xcode.py", line 140, in GenerateBuildParams
    for lib in selected_target_generated['libs']:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/apple/.apportable/SDK/bin/apportable", line 782, in 
    run(env)
  File "/Users/apple/.apportable/SDK/bin/apportable", line 723, in run
    results = actionsargs.action
  File "/Users/apple/.apportable/SDK/bin/apportable", line 86, in LoadAction
    return env.LoadApp(site_init.BuildApplication(env, env['BUILD_TARGET']))
  File "/Users/apple/.apportable/SDK/site_scons/site_init.py", line 388, in BuildApplication
    return build.App(env, app_sconscript)
  File "/Users/apple/.apportable/SDK/site_scons/build/**init**.py", line 481, in App
    generated, generated_path, main_module = xcode.GenerateBuildParams(env)
  File "/Users/apple/.apportable/SDK/site_scons/build/xcode.py", line 140, in GenerateBuildParams
    for lib in selected_target_generated['libs']:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable'

Answer (score 2):

As Philippe Hausler said in their support forum

> We are working on a fix still, hopefully it should be ready by next week.
>
> I personally have my Xcode 4 stored at /Applications/Xcode4.app and Xcode 5 stored at /Applications/Xcode5.app
>   to build with current stuff I have to switch via this:
>
> sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode4.app/Contents/Developer

Here is forum URL https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/apportable-discuss worth to check on a daily basis.

Cheers,
Hubert

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add that I tried an empty project because I got very similar errors with my other projects, which got even bigger error list.

I got the latest version 1.024

I got stuff to compile before with Xcode 4.61 before.  I don't know what happned now.

Answer (score 0):

The 1.0.26 SDK, released today, has initial support for Xcode 5.

Run `apportable update` to update your installation.