# Apportable Xcode 5

Tags: apportable

Is Apportable updated for Xcode 5?

And if it is how do I update?

Comment: Huh?  Just huh.  So what have you tried?  Perhaps the Apportable website might have an answer?

Comment: I am thinking it may have JUST been updated....

Comment: And I want to use it RIGHT now.  I have someone waiting to port apps over.

Comment: This is useful : http://docs.apportable.com/all.html

Comment: Duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19043353/apportable-xcode-5-empty-project-compile-error

Answer (score 1):

The 1.0.26 SDK, released earlier this week, has initial support for Xcode 5.

Run `apportable update` to update your installation.